# VideoJs flv and chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I have a little problem with videojs: flv videos plays well in chrome, however the timing and the timebar don't respond (timing 00:00 even if the video is playing )

I don't have this problem in IE or FF

Thanks for suggesting me some ideas

Comment: Some code to demonstrate your problem would be useful. Try setting up a test case on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

For playing .flv videos you can using FlowPlayer.org

For playing other than flv videos you can using html 5.0  tag in Chrome, Firefox & IE 11